# Fancybox 2.0.1 inline content not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I followed the tutorial on the site to get inline content working. Even checked their source and made changes to my own site.

Here is the site: http://miuzer.com/new/
Check the links in the upper right. About works, but register and login don't as their content is inline. What is the issue here?

I find a lot of js libraries are buggy, overcomplicated and poorly documented, fancybox is one of the worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete this line:

```
<a id="popup_img" style="display:none" href="img/popup_img.jpg"><img src="img/popup_img.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Alter about/register/login part like this:

```
<div class="header-content">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="img/popup_img.jpg">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#register-dialog">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login-dialog">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Delete these lines from `interface.js`

```
$('#popup_img').fancybox();
$('#register-dialog').fancybox({'type':'inline'});
$('#login-dialog').fancybox({'type':'inline'});
// $('#popup_img').click();
```

and add this line instead:

```
$('.header-content ul a').fancybox();
```

By the way, it's a very well documented and well written [plugin](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and I can't say same thing for your code...